# $X$ Hausdorff space, $Y \subseteq X$ compact $\implies $ Y closed

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

> Suppose $X$ is a hausdorff Space and $Y \subseteq X$ compact. Then $Y$
>   must be closed

My Attempt: We need to find an open set $O$ such that $O \subseteq X \setminus Y$, then $Y$ is closed. Let us take an open coven $\mathcal{O}$ of $Y$. Since $Y$ is compact, we can find a finite subcover $\mathcal{O}' = \{ O_1, ... , O_n \} $ such that all $O_i $ are open in $X$ and $Y \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} O_i $ Here I am stuck. Can I assume all these $O_i$ are disjoint since $X$ is hausdorff ? And pick one of them (the one that lies outsite $Y$) Therefore showing $Y$ is closed? Can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Why does the existence of an open set $O \subseteq X\setminus Y$ imply $Y$ is closed?

Comment: This is a well known problem. See, e.g., http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Subspace_of_Hausdorff_Space_is_Closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you need to show that $X\setminus Y$ **is** open. No matter what $Y$ is, there’s always at least one open **subset** of $X\setminus Y$, namely, $\varnothing$.

You’re on the wrong track altogether, because you’ve not seen how to make use of the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff. One way to show that $X\setminus Y$ is open is to show that each point of $X\setminus Y$ has an open nbhd disjoint from $Y$, so let $x\in X\setminus Y$. $X$ is Hausdorff, so for each $y\in Y$ there are open sets $U_y$ and $V_y$ such that $x\in U_y$, $y\in V_y$, and $U_y\cap V_y=\varnothing$. Clearly $\{V_y:y\in Y\}$ is an open cover, so there is a finite $F\subseteq Y$ such that $\{V_y:y\in F\}$ covers $Y$. Can you see how to use this fact to find an open nbhd of $x$ that is disjoint from $Y$?

Comment: Can we say $O' = \{ V_{y1},...,V_{yn} \} $ is an open subcover of $Y$ and since $V_{yi} \cap U_{yi} = \varnothing$, then we can put $O = \bigcap_{i} U_{yi} $ So $O$ is an open set containing $x$ outside of $Y$. IS this correct?

Comment: @Citizen: You do want to work with $\{U_y:y\in F\}$, but you need to do something else with these sets; their union may be too big, having non-empty intersection with $Y$. (It’s even possible that each $U_y$ has non-empty intersection with $Y$.)